# Repeatedly apply a bivariate function with one argument running over a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I'd like to know how, given symbols `f` and `g`, and a list `{a,b,c,...}`, to produce the expression:

```
f[f[f[g,a],b],c]
```

I can get the result if I do:

```
Apply[f,{{{g,a},b},c},{0,2}]
```

but then how do I manipulate the list `{a,b,c}` into `{{{g,a},b},c}`? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicates?:  [(7924)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121), [(25474)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/121).  (Do we really have so simpler questions dealing with `Fold`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};
Fold[f, g, {a, b, c, d}]
(* f[f[f[f[g, a], b], c], d] *)
```

Comment: Fold. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this at home; use bbgodfrey's solution.  :-)

However, `Fold` is also the answer to your question on how to transform `{a, b, c, d, e}` into `{{{{{g, a}, b}, c}, d}, e}`. But you don't have follow with a fancy application of `Apply`; a simple substitution is all you need.

```
data = {a, b, c, d, e};
tmp = Fold[List, g, data]
```

> `{{{{{g, a}, b}, c}, d}, e}`

```
tmp /. List -> f
```

> `f[f[f[f[f[g, a], b], c], d], e]`

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks for the info!